# CouchDB V2.0 required hardware and software configuration

Tags: couchdb, hardware

I want to deploy a couchDB V2 to manage a DataBase with 30 Terabyte. Can you please suggest me the minimal hardware configuration ?
- Number of server
- Number of nodes
- Number of cluster
- Number of replication
- Size of disk per couchDB instance
- etc.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You want 3 servers minimum due to quorum.  Other than that, I would recommend at least 2 clusters of 3.  If you want to be geographically dispersed, then you want a cluster of 3 in each location.  I think those are the basic rules.

Answer (score 0):

If its a single database with 30 TB, I think there needs to some way to avoid it... Here are some ideas:

- Look at the nature of the docs stored in it and see if you can move out the type of doc that are frequently accessed to a different db and change the application for using it.
- As suggested by fred above, the 3 servers and multiple clusters
- Backup and recovery - If the database is 30TB, the backup would also take the same space. You might want the backup normally in a different datacenter. Replication for 30 TB will take a lot of time.
- Read the docs of CouchDB on how deletion happens, you might want to use the filtered replication which will again take more space.

Keeping the above points in mind you might want 3 servers as suggested by fred to run couchdb for your business and more servers to maintain backups and doc deletions over a long time.